How do I identify the last security update and roll it back/remove it?
My Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
LSS:
Where I live the government is known to have the capability to pollute security patches and updates, in other words when using Ubuntu's default GUI update interface below

I could have unwittingly downloaded malware ridden "updates".
What I do is that using CLI, I download the updates from very specific sources in hoping to defeat that.
Lately I accidentally used the GUI interface shown above by unintentionally pressing the space bar.
Naturally now I want to identify the update patch that I applied and roll it back so I can manually redo the update.
Prior to this mishandling I update ubuntu quite frequently so I'm confident not a lot of update patches were applied - quite likely only one patch was installed, and it was a security update, again, similar to what is shown in the picture.
Not only that I also did not apply any further updates beyond that point to make future roll-back easier.
How should I accomplish that? To summarize, I want to identify the last patch/patches I applied, and remove them.

There's an apt history file in /var/log/apt/history.log that will list all the updates each task did, and then you can attempt to revert the software to the previous version.  However, you will need to disable automatic updates, which means your system is likely to be unsafe in the future.

Strange the history.log is completely empty with zero bytes. @ThomasWard

@ThomasWard I opened history.log.1 and it only showed CLI updates. Maybe the GUI updates are in term.log.x?

history.log rotates monthly, so an empty file at the beginning of a month seems like expected behavior. If the event happened late last month, check near the bottom of that month's log.

"the government is known to have the capability to pollute security patches and updates" It's a myth. Never actually seen in the wild on Ubuntu, which has layers of strong protections. If you have personal experience of this happening to your system, the professional security engineers of the Ubuntu Security Team would love to have a chat and learn the details from you.

@user535733 I'd like to know what enabled you to have such a level of confidence. There's always a way. There's always a loophole somewhere. Signatures can be faked, authorities can be spoofed. Checksums can be forged. Nothing is truly safe against a determined attacker with the sufficient skill level. The best argument would be "Why" not "How".

@user535733 I found in both "term" and "history" file records showing that nothing was updated except certificates being added, which is strange unless adding certificates is considered by ubuntu to be a form of security update. And not surprisingly, the certificate authority is based in the country I live in.

If you are sure the ISO you used to install your Ubuntu was verified - you can download a manifest of packages and their versions installed in that ISO.
From https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest
accountsservice 22.07.5-2ubuntu1.5
acl 2.3.1-1
acpi-support    0.144
acpid   1:2.0.33-1ubuntu1
adcli   0.9.1-1ubuntu2
adduser 3.118ubuntu5
adwaita-icon-theme  41.0-1ubuntu1

You can then query your system and see if any packages were upgraded and proceed to downgrade.
The base version from the manifest should be present on the apt archive as well - which creates additional problems.
This will likely break your system.
TLDR: Don't do it. Do a fresh install if your thread model is like this.
